# jsonata $zip with multiple arguments

Tags: json, jsonata

With:

```
$zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

It produces the expected result:

```
[
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [3, 6, 9]
]
```

How should it work here for example:

```
(
    $arr := [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
    $zip($arr);
)
```

Which produces:

```
[
  [
    [1, 2, 3]
  ],
  [
    [4, 5, 6]
  ],
  [
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
]
```

?

My use case is that the array I want to pass to `$zip` will have an unknown number of inner arrays.

I'm using the JSONata Exerciser v2.0.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should do the trick:

```
(
  $arr := [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
  $len := $max($map($arr, function($innerArray, $index, $array) { $count($innerArray) }));
  $map([0..$len-1], function($rowIdx, $idx, $array) {
    $map($arr, function($innerArray, $innerIdx, $innerArr) { $innerArray[$rowIdx] })
  })
)
```

You can check out this solution in Stedi JSONata Playground: https://stedi.link/dc9jvJ2

[image]

Comment: That's pretty smart the way you wrote the underlying logic of the `$zip` function in jsonata... https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/blob/b520b88f8d9b582c2f64a3a49f5654d9e0124f00/src/functions.js#L1570-L1593. However, I'm looking for an answer that uses `$zip`.